# How can I view "Orders" and/or "Product Orders" in Salesforce Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-experience, order

When viewing our Salesforce account in non-lightning mode, "Orders" and "Product Orders" ( both built-in objects ) can be viewed.  However when the UI is switched to the Lightning Experience, I'm unable to find either in the sidebar or under sub-sections under the Account level.

Is there a way to view Account Orders in Salesforce Lightning?  If not, is there a custom way or perhaps is viewing Orders on the roadmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think viewing Orders and Product Orders is supported currently, though I'm sure it's on the road map, there is no way to know when it will come.

As for a custom way to do it I'm sure you could create a Lightning Component to display them, or a Visualforce Page.